# SWT composite and group

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I want to put text inside the composite and group, but for some reason, the text didn't show up on the UI. Can anyone give me some suggestion? thank you!

```
    data = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    data.horizontalSpan = 2;
    Group group1 = new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
    group1.setText("This is my group");
    group1.setLayoutData(data);
    Text text = new Text(group1, SWT.NONE);
    text.setText("Group test with label");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group1.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
```

this can solve the problem.

Comment: ...or any `Layout`. Thanks!